# @ApiImplicitParam for Map<String, String> objects

Tags: java, collections, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have a API which accepts One string, and One MAP as the input.

```
public ModelClass getMyApi(String inparm, Map<String, String> myValues)
```

I am wondering how can i capture MAP input in swagger document using `@ApiImplicitParams`, `@ApiImplicitParam` annotations.

I have tried with like this

```
 @ApiImplicitParam(name="myValues", value="Validation Values Map", required =
         true, dataType = "Map", paramType = "query")
```

But no luck.

Note: Am using `Swagger-servlet` Module.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the Map capturing the body or query params?

Comment: I found a relevant answer here but cannot comment on your question so pasting the link here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37258271/3759060

Comment: Did you ever get this working?