# Why `additionalProperties` is the way to represent Dictionary/Map in Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0

Tags: dictionary, hash, mapping, swagger, openapi

Although I have seen the examples in the [OpenAPI spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#schemaObject):

> ```
> type: object
> additionalProperties:
>   $ref: '#/definitions/ComplexModel'
> ```

it isn't obvious to me *why* the use of `additionalProperties` is the correct schema for a Map/Dictionary.

It also doesn't help that the only concrete thing that the spec has to say about `additionalProperties` is:

> The following properties are taken from the JSON Schema definition but their definitions were adjusted to the Swagger Specification. Their definition is the same as the one from JSON Schema, only where the original definition references the JSON Schema definition, the Schema Object definition is used instead.
>
> - items
> - allOf
> - properties
> - additionalProperties

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Chen, I think [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41240118/776186) is correct.

Some further background that might be helpful:

In JavaScript, which was the original context for JSON, an object is like a hash map of strings to values, where some values are data, others are functions. You can think of each name-value pair as a property. But JavaScript doesn't have classes, so the property names are not predefined, and each object can have its own independent set of properties.

JSON Schema uses the `properties` keyword to validate name-value pairs that are known in advance; and uses `additionalProperties` (or `patternProperties`, not supported in OpenAPI 2.0) to validate properties that are not known.

For clarity:

- The property names, or "keys" in the map, must be strings. They cannot be numbers, or any other value.
- As you said, the property names *should* be unique. Unfortunately the JSON spec doesn't strictly require uniqueness, but uniqueness is recommended, and expected by most JSON implementations.  More background [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object?lq=1).
- `properties` and `additionalProperties` can be used alone or in combination.  When additionalProperties is used alone, without properties, the object essentially functions as a `map<string, T>` where T is the type described in the additionalProperties sub-schema. Maybe that helps to answer your original question.
- When evaluating an object against a single schema, if a property name matches one of those specified in `properties`, its value only needs to be valid against the sub-schema provided for that property. The `additionalProperties` sub-schema, if provided, will only be used to validate properties that *are not* included in the `properties` map.
- There are some limitations of `additionalProperties` as implemented in Swagger's core Java libraries. I've documented these limitations [here](https://support.reprezen.com/support/solutions/articles/6000162892-support-for-additionalproperties-in-swagger-2-0-schemas).

Comment: Epstien, although your answer is correct, I am not sure if it addresses the question I was struggling with: How come `additionalProperty` maps (pun not intended) to a dictionary or map. Also if my answer is *mostly* correct, it is *somewhat* incorrect, and I didn't understand from your answer what is incorrect in it.

Comment: Chen, thanks for the comments. I updated my answer with more details that I hope will be helpful to you and other readers. The focus of my answer was to provide some further background and insight, not to correct your answer. Hopfully my 3rd bullet point, taken in context, answers your original question (though not necessarily better than your own answer).

Comment: Chen, there were only a couple of points in your answer that might not be 100% correct, and I tried to address those in my answer.

(1) Where your answer says "keys (their names or number)", that seems to suggest that properties can use number values as keys. In fact, the names have to be strings.

(2) Where you said "additionalProperties will match any property name," Maybe obvious, but I thought I should point out that it _won't_ match property names included under the `properties` keyword.

Comment: Ted, thanks for that comment. When I wrote "their names or number" I meant to say "the names of the keys or how many keys there are", I fixed my answer to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 50):

First thing, I found a [better explanation for `additionalProperties`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/668#issuecomment-218829120):

> For an object, if this is given, in addition to the properties defined in `properties` all other property names are allowed. Their values must each match the schema object given here. If this is not given, no other properties than those defined in `properties` are allowed.

So here is how I finally understood this:

Using `properties`, we can define a known set of properties similar to [Python's namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), however if we wish to have something more like [Python's dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict), or any other hash/map where we can't specify how many keys there are nor what they are in advance, we should use `additionalProperties`.

`additionalProperties` will match any property name (that will act as the `dict`'s key, and the `$ref` or `type` will be the schema of the `dict`'s value, and since there should not be more than one properties with the same name for every given object, we will get the enforcement of unique keys.

Note that unlike Python's `dict` that accepts any immutable value as a key, since the keys here are in essence property names, they must be strings. (Thanks [Ted Epstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/776186/) for that clarification). This limitation can be tracked down to `pair := string : value` in the [json specification](http://www.json.org/).