# List of Dictionaries in Swagger

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using https://github.com/rochacbruno/flasgger for swagger in my python-flask application. I need to send an array of dictionaries (or json) in the value of a parameter. But I couldn't find any such type in the documentation of swagger (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/). Any Suggestions on how users are achieving this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of a property called `test` that holds an array of String-String dictionaries:

```
      test:
        type: array
        items:
          type: object
          additionalProperties:
            type: string
```

Hope I can help you. A similar answer, describing the `additionalProperties` field, was given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41242185/8745384