# Which is the correct way to restrict openapi type in properties?

Tags: openapi

I have the following so far:

```
Links:
  description: Must contain links objects
  type: object
  properties:
    $ref: "#/components/schemas/Link"
ErrorLinks:
  allOf:
    - $ref: "#/components/schemas/Links"
    - properties:
        about:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/Link"
```

In `Links`, I don't care what the names of any `properties` are, just that they are all `Link` objects. In `ErrorLinks`, I expect there to be an `about` property, which is also an `Link` object.

Is this the correct way to define that, or am I saying (in `Links`) that I expect the `properties` node itself to be a `Link` object?

I find the openapi documentation a little lacking in helpful examples and the above validates, so I am not entirely sure.

Comment: These questions have also been answered in [Swagger: map of <string, Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36136885/113116) and [Property reference to Model on swagger 2.0 (nesting)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26287962/113116), just replace `#/definitions/` (OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 syntax) with `#/components/schemas/` (OpenAPI 3.0 syntax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In `Links`, I don't care what the names of any properties are, just that they are all `Link` objects.

`Links` is a dictionary (hashmap) then. Dictionaries are defined using `additionalProperties`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37258271/113116):

```yaml
Links:
  description: Must contain links objects
  type: object
  additionalProperties:
    $ref: "#/components/schemas/Link"
```

> In `ErrorLinks`, I expect there to be an `about` property, which is also an `Link` object.

You are almost there. There's no need for `allOf`, you just need a simple object schema:

```yaml
ErrorLinks:
  type: object
  properties:
    about:
      $ref: "#/components/schemas/Link"
  required:
    - about
```