# How to have multiple infinite objects without an array - Open API / Swagger

Tags: json, yaml, swagger, openapi, codegen

I'm trying to setup an open api spec for the following snippet of JSON:

```
                    "test1": {
                        "1739573957": {
                            "tester1": 123,
                            "tester2": "Company"
                        },
                        "64903826718": {
                            "tester1": 123,
                            "tester2": "Company"
                        }
                        "5902849189": {
                            "tester1": 123,
                            "tester2": "Company"
                        }
                    }
```

The objects inside test1 have randomized guids and are listed in a way that typically would be an array, but is not. There could potentially be an infinite number of objects inside test 1. Anyone know how to set this up?

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [Swagger: map of <string, Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36136885/113116), [How to write OpenAPI 3 (Swagger) specification for property name in `map` object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46552863/113116)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test1` is a string-to-object dictionary and can be defined as follows (assuming OpenAPI 3):

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    Tester:  # Or however you would name the nested objects
      tester1:
        type: integer
        example: 123
      tester2:
        type: string
        example: Company

...
test1:
  type: object
  additionalProperties:
    $ref: '#/components/schemas/Tester'

  # Optional example for the `test1` property
  example:
    '1739573957':
      tester1: 123
      tester2: Company
    '64903826718':
      tester1: 123
      tester2: Company
```

> The objects inside test1 have randomized guids

In OpenAPI 3.1, you can use [`patternProperties`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46553255/113116) instead of `additionalProperties` to define that the keys inside `test1` are numeric strings. Earlier OpenAPI versions don't have a way to define the format of dictionary keys.

```yaml
# openapi: 3.1.0

test1:
  type: object
  patternProperties:  # <-----
    '^\d+$':          # <-----
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Tester'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [free-form-object](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#free-form):

> A free-form object (arbitrary property/value pairs) is defined as:
> `type: object`
>
> This is equivalent to
>
> ```
> type: object 
> additionalProperties: true
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> type: object 
> additionalProperties: {}
> ```

However, if you can change the API, I'd highly recommend to change it to an array of tests or whatever the object defines. Put the id as property into this object and you're good to go. This makes creating DTOs for it a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks! This made me read up more on free-form-objects and was very helpful!